# Solr facet on a multi value field

Tags: solr, solrnet

Is it possible to facet on a multi value field using SolrNet? I have a date field but it needs to be multivalued as it's for binaries. When I try to run my application and apply a sort I get an error:

> Apache Tomcat/7.0.29 - Error
>   report
>
> ## 525D76;}--> HTTP Status 400 - can not sort on multivalued field: date
>
> noshade=\"noshade\">
>
> **type** Status report
>
> **message**
>   can not sort on multivalued field:
>   date
>
> **description** The request sent by the client
>   was syntactically incorrect (can not sort on multivalued field:
>   date).
>
> #### Apache
>   Tomcat/7.0.29

I've had a read online and it seems like most of the answers suggest that this isn't possible - is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which of the multiple of values would you like to sort multiValued field on? Solr can't decide for you.

The usual answer is to create a second field just for sort, it does not need to be stored. Then, you use Update Request Processor to populate that second field from the first and you only keep one value which will be used for sort.

The relevant URPs - in this order - are:

1. [CloneField](http://www.solr-start.com/javadoc/solr-lucene/org/apache/solr/update/processor/CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory.html)
2. [DefaultValue](http://www.solr-start.com/javadoc/solr-lucene/org/apache/solr/update/processor/DefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory.html) - in case you have optional fields and you want a sane default
3. One of the [FieldValueSubset](http://www.solr-start.com/javadoc/solr-lucene/org/apache/solr/update/processor/FieldValueSubsetUpdateProcessorFactory.html) children (Min, Max, First, Last)

Comment: Hi Alexandre, many thanks for your reply. So the date is multi-valued because a document can have more than one date (created, modified, accessed etc depending on the type of document). I simply want to get the created date. Can I achieve this with the approach you have suggested?

Comment: You just need to get created date into a separate field. With this approach you can probably use MinFieldValue, as created should also be the earliest. 
The other option is to send them to the document in the individual fields and copyField them into a joint multi-valued field. These two are reverse of each other.

Comment: Thank you Alexandre. I went with your suggestion, I created another field for sorting that contains the date I want to sort. Thanks again.